# How to make associative array from CSV file using ColdFusion?

Tags: arrays, csv, coldfusion, associative-array, coldfusion-11

Can anybody explain how to make associative array from CSV file in ColdFusion. I have implemented this in PHP but needed now in ColdFusion as well.
I have first row as header and want to use them as keys and all rows from CSV except the first one as value in assoc array.

Please let me know what you need further.
Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry . I meant first row. Thank you

Comment: Just for completeness, an "associative array" in ColdFusion is called a "structure".

Answer (score 4):

If you read the file with the `<cfhttp>` tag, and include a `name` attribute, you will have a ColdFusion query object at your disposal.  While this is not called an associative array, it effectively is one.

Code samples and a more detailed explanation are available here.  https://www.bennadel.com/blog/1903-parsing-csv-data-with-coldfusion-s-cfhttp-tag.htm

Comment: Let me try this one then

Comment: This is a great way to set the information up like you need it. Just make sure to note Ben's limitations.

Answer (score 4):

We use a java library called OpenCSV. Here is a page with an example.

https://dev.to/gamesover/convert-csv-file-to-coldfusion-query-object-using-coldfusion-opencsv-java-49ho

Answer (score 1):

As others have already said, you can easily convert a CSV file into a query object using `cfhttp`.  Also, since you're using ColdFusion 11, you can convert a query object into json using `serializeJson` with the `struct` option.  Then `deserializeJson` to convert it back into an array of structs.  All you need is 2 lines of code and your done.

See code example and link to TryCF gist below.

https://trycf.com/gist/b8f30141e8e6b588a396fb1051a38447/acf11?theme=monokai

```
<cfscript>
    cfhttp( 
        name="myData", 
        url="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sauravg94/test-repo/master/MOCK_DATA.csv", 
        firstrowasheaders="true",
        method="GET"
    );
    myArrayOfStructs = deserializeJson(serializeJson(myData, "struct"));

    writedump(myData);
    writeDump(myArrayOfStructs);

</cfscript>
```

## EDIT

Code updated due to Dan Bracuk's comment where he pointed out that I did not answer the question that was asked.

Comment: Slight problem, nothing about json was asked in the question.

Comment: @DanBracuk Silly, me.  You're correct.  I'll update my answer to reflect what the OP was after.  Mea culpa.